# Inno Setup Testing installer exit code

Tags: inno-setup

How can I access the return code of Inno Setup based installer?

For example, [this](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupexitcodes) documentation says that exit code will be 1 if "Setup failed to initialize". In my installer, in some cases, code returns `False` from `InitializeSetup()`. I am running the installer with `/silent` flag on command prompt. If I `echo %errorlevel%`, I get 0.

Relevant portion of code from the `InitializeSetup()` function:

```pascal
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  // In silent mode, set Result to false so as to exit before wizard is
  // launched in case setup cannot continue.
  if WizardSilent() then
  begin
    // CompareVersion() logically returns the -1, 0 or 1 based on
    // whether the version being installed is less than, equal to or greater
    // than version already installed. Returns 0 is there is no existing
    // installation.
    ResultCode := CompareVersion();
    if ResultCode < 0 then
    begin
      Result := False;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;

  Result := True;
end;
```

From command line, here is how I am running and capturing return value:

```
C:\VersionCheck>myinstaller.exe /Silent

C:\VersionCheck>echo %errorlevel%
0

C:\VersionCheck>
```

The log file shows :

```
2016-09-29 08:05:11.259   Log opened. (Time zone: UTC-07:00)
2016-09-29 08:05:11.259   Setup version: Inno Setup version 5.5.9 (u)
2016-09-29 08:05:11.259   Original Setup EXE: C:\VersionCheck\myinstaller.exe
2016-09-29 08:05:11.259   Setup command line: /SL5="$9051C,3445541,131584,C:\VersionCheck\myinstaller.exe" /Silent
2016-09-29 08:05:11.259   Windows version: 6.3.9600  (NT platform: Yes)
2016-09-29 08:05:11.259   64-bit Windows: Yes
2016-09-29 08:05:11.259   Processor architecture: x64
2016-09-29 08:05:11.259   User privileges: Administrative
2016-09-29 08:05:11.259   64-bit install mode: Yes
2016-09-29 08:05:11.259   Created temporary directory: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\is-TQB2V.tmp
2016-09-29 08:05:11.275   Installed version component : 3
2016-09-29 08:05:11.275   Updating to version component : 0
2016-09-29 08:05:11.275   This computer already has a more recent version (3.5.0.0) of XYZ. If you wantto downgrade to version 0.0.0.0 then uninstall and try again. Setup will exit.
2016-09-29 08:05:11.275   InitializeSetup returned False; aborting.
2016-09-29 08:05:11.275   Got EAbort exception.
2016-09-29 08:05:11.275   Deinitializing Setup.
2016-09-29 08:05:11.275   Log closed.
```

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your test is not valid.

When you execute a GUI application (the installer) from a command-line, the console does not wait for the program to finish. So the `%errorlevel%` cannot contain an exit code of the application (installer), as it has not finished at the time yet.

In this case the `%errorlevel%` reflects errors (but not success) of starting the application only.

Also note that the silent mode has actually no effects on this. The non-silent mode behaves the same.

---

But if you add the exactly same commands to a batch file (`.bat`), it will work. As the batch file waits for the application to finish.

```
C:\VersionCheck>test.bat

C:\VersionCheck>myinstaller.exe /Silent

C:\VersionCheck>echo 1
1
C:\VersionCheck>
```

Where the `test.bat` contains your two commands:

```
myinstaller.exe /Silent
echo %errorlevel%
```